# I'm trying to add a popup modal to my WordPress website but in is not working

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[image]I'm trying to add a popup modal to my WordPress website, for this, I added custom elementor code, and the code is executed properly in preview but not working on the live website.

It shows an error in inspect :
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('') does not match the recipient window's origin ('').

[Intervention] Images loaded lazily and replaced with placeholders. Load events are deferred. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2048113

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used JQuery instead of `$` and it works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// jQuery code is in here

});
```